# How can I speed up an integration of an integration function?

Tags: numerical-integration

I have to find a plot of an integral function that contains an integral function, but the running time is too slow. Here is the code:

```
H = 0.07358;
Ω = 0.75;
Λ = Ω*3*H;
lE = 3.79*10^-4;
l = 13.778128047493817;
k = 1;
    
a[t_?NumericQ] := ((1 - Ω)/Ω)^(1/3)*Sinh[(3*H*Sqrt[Ω]*t)/2]^(2/3)            
f[t_?NumericQ] := -((1/(5*Sqrt[Cosh[Sqrt[3 Λ]/2*t]^2]))*
            ((-8*Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 5/6,
              11/6, -Sinh[Sqrt[3 Λ]/2*t]^2] + (4 + Cosh[2*Sqrt[3 Λ]/2*t])*Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 5/6, 11/6, -Sinh[Sqrt[3 Λ]/2*t]^2])*Sinh[Sqrt[3 Λ]/2*t]^(2/3)))        
β[t_?NumericQ] := Sin[k*(l - t)]        
Z[t_?NumericQ] := β[t]*f[t]        
ft[t_?NumericQ] := -((Sqrt[Λ] Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t] (-8 Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 5/6, 11/6, -Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ]t ]^2] + (4 + Cosh[Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t]) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 5/6, 11/
               6, -Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t]^2]))/(5 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t]^2] Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t]^(
           1/3))) + (Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t] (-8 Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 5/6, 11/6, -Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t]^2] + (4 + Cosh[Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t]) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 5/6, 11/6, -Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t]^2]) Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t]^(5/3))/(10 (Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ]t]^2)^(3/2)) - 1/(5 Sqrt[Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t]^2])
        Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t]^(2/3) (1/(2 Sqrt[3])
           5 Sqrt[Λ] (4 + Cosh[Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t]) Coth[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t] (-Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 5/6, 11/6, -Sinh[ 1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t]^2] + 1/Sqrt[
            1 + Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t]^2]) - 1/Sqrt[3] 20 Sqrt[Λ] Coth[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t] (-Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), 5/6, 11/6, -Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t]^2] + Sqrt[1 + Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t]^2]) + Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 5/6, 11/6, -Sinh[1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t]^2] Sinh[Sqrt[3] Sqrt[Λ] t])
at[t_?NumericQ] := (H Sqrt[Λ] ((1 - Ω)/Ω)^(1/3) Cosh[3/2 H Sqrt[Λ] t])/Sinh[3/2 H Sqrt[Λ] t]^(1/3)
Zt[t_?NumericQ] := ft[t]*β[t]    
h[t_?NumericQ] := (H Sqrt[Λ] (-1 + Ω^(-1))^(1/3) Coth[(3 H Sqrt[Λ] t)/2])/((1 - Ω)/Ω)^(1/3)      
βz[t_?NumericQ] := β'[t]        
Zz[t_?NumericQ] := f[t]*βz[t]        
k1z[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(2*Zt[y]/a[y]) - Zz[y]/a[y]^2, {y, l, t}, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", 
        "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, PrecisionGoal -> 1]    
F[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[k1z[y], {y, l,t}, 
      Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", 
        "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, PrecisionGoal -> 1]

Plot[F[t], {t, lE, 1}, PlotStyle -> Black ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

These are quite oscillating functions. The evaluation of `k1z[t]` takes 3.71 seconds, and I never get a result for the integration of `k1z[t]`, that is `F[t]`.

How could I speed up this integration? I think that the problem is due to the difficulty of the expression. Is there a way to improve my code?

Answer (score 1):

after deleting a superfluous closing square bracket in function ft

```
(4 + Sqrt[3] Sqrt[\[CapitalLambda]] t])
```

the plot appears after about 7 seconds,
but I have no idea of the correctness of your formulas...
Is

```
Zt[\[Lambda]_?NumericQ] := ft[t]*\[Beta][t]
```

really a function of [Lambda] ?

[image]

Comment: Sorry! Yes, there was an error in the code. Now I correct it.